# Finding distinct rows in scope with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two models in my rails project: persons and an embeded collection, cities. there is also a spatial index on the cities. I want to find all persons near one city.

```
class Person
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps
 embeds_many :cities
 scope :nearby, ->(location, distance) { where('cities.location' => 
                    {'$near' => location , '$maxDistance' => distance})}


class City
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  embedded_in :person
  field :city
  field :location, type: Array  #0: latitude, 1: longitude

location_in_new_york = [40.71892, -74.00131]
```

My query would be

```
Person.nearby(location_in_new_york, 1)
```

But doing so a person with two cities which are very close to each other get found twice. How can I avoid this behavior? I dont want to reduce this in ruby, because I would like to keep my scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not as clean as just being able to call `.distinct` on a criteria, this workaround gives the expected results:

```
Person.find(Person.nearby(location_in_new_york, 1).distinct(:_id))
```

This doesn't work (as written) as a scope, however, so you'd have to make it a class method. Personally, I would look into adding a patch to mongoid to add a `.unique` method that does what you want (since MongoDB is responsible for returning field values instead of documents when you use its distinct operator: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation )

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. Problem is though, the result of the find method is an array instead of a criteria, and it gets an order criteria added and the result will be paged. Both wont work with an array. I agree adding a patch seems the best choice.

Comment: Does a Person really need to have multiple cities in your data model? That would be the easiest thing to change. Otherwise, yeah, that's why I recommended doing it as a class method, because it's not chainable. You can call order before you do the location query, and paginate the array (hopefully there aren't too many results), or do a "Load More" rather than full pagination.

Comment: Unfortunately it needs multiple cities. But yes till we find a better solution we will going without them. I also saw there is an uniqueDocs option (http://bit.ly/hrPjfS) but it does not work for nearby querys.